# Mysql Variable returning null value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello Everyone i am facing a problem that i am doing some calculations and storing it into variable its working fine but when i declare another variable which is equal to that variable is returning null.

This my query

```
$data = DB::table('extended_data')
    ->select(
    DB::raw('@Time_Spent_at_Sea := SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(SUBTIME(CONVERT("23:59 GMT", TIME), CONVERT(COSP_date_GMT, TIME))))')
    , DB::raw('@Total := @Time_Spent_at_Sea')
    )->get();
```

and this is my output

```
{"voyage-duration-chart-api":[{"@Time_Spent_at_Sea := SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(SUBTIME(CONVERT(\"23:59 GMT\", TIME), CONVERT(COSP_date_GMT, TIME))))":"45793140","@Total := @Time_Spent_at_Sea":null}]}
```

Comment: Provide table structure and example data on sqlfiddle.com or db-fiddle.com. Also provide expected results as a ascii (text formatted) table. For now i voteclose the question to be unclear clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Explain in English the conversion you desire.  (I can't figure out the query.)